# The Current Project Not Supported error for Application Insights in Windows 10 Universal apps

Tags: azure, windows-10, azure-storage, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

When i created new windows 10 app, i want to add application insights to my app, it showing the error like as below image. Any one please help me to how to add application insights to my app. I also tried the process of this link http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/08/12/adding-application-insights-to-a-windows-10-universal-app/, when fallowing this process .config file is not adding to my project..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is Transitioning mobile apps to use Microsoft's HockeyApp instead.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transitioning-mobile-apps-from-application-insights-to-hockeyapp/

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Visual Studio 2015 update2?

I can successfully integrate Application Insights into my project following the same steps in http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/08/12/adding-application-insights-to-a-windows-10-universal-app/.

FYI, please find my steps below:

1) Create a win store app in Azure Applciation Insight Service

2) Create a blank UWP project

3) Config the ApplicationInsights.config of your UWP app, which is automatically created by VS, with the correct InstrumentationKey

4) Modify the app's construction function in app.xaml.cs as below. You can adjust according to your specific requirements.

```
  Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync(
                Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Metadata |  Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.UnhandledException|
                Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Session);
```

I strongly recommend that you take a look at [HockeApp](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb), since just as Ken mentioned, MS is transferring mobile apps to HockeyApp right now. Application Insights will stop support for mobile apps by June 15, 2016.

Comment: The latest UWP SDK supports User Metrics including users and sessions data.  You could Nuget the latest UWP version. As about page view, there is no ETA on this.